# Can't include a template multiple time in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to include a template multiple time in Twig.

Here is an explanation of my case:

I have the original template, lets say `index.html.twig`. This template include diffirent templates : `part1.html.twig part2.html.twig` etc..

My goal is to include a final template `extra.html.twig` to each sub templates **(part1, part2)**. I've made the test, who concluded that I can include the final template just once. Twig detects that this template is already concluded and don't display it twice or three.

*How can I achieve this result ?*

```
|index.html.twig
  |include part1.html.twig
     |include extra.html.twig
  |include part2.html.twig
     |include extra.html.twig
```

[image]

**UPDATE** :

```
{% block  file_upload %}
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="upload_files" style="float: right">
        {{ form_widget(upload_form.button) }}
    </div>

    {{ form_widget(upload_form.attachment) }}

    <table class="table table-files-preview" hidden>
        <thead>
        <td>{% trans %}NAME{% endtrans %}</td>
        <td>{% trans %}TYPE{% endtrans %}</td>
        <td>{% trans %}SIZE{% endtrans %}</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody-file-preview">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" id="files_source" value="{{ source }}">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Not sure what your asking, but should work as is. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/wepkh2), please post your template if i'm seeing this wrong

Comment: Your example shows that we can include a template multiple time, but not the same template. In my case I want to include the same template, two or three time.

Comment: Just tested on a project (duplicated an include line), does not give any error and displays it twice correctly. What error do you get ?

Comment: Also, if you duplicate the code in @DarkBee fiddle, it works as well. https://twigfiddle.com/wepkh2/2

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I include my template many times. But the framework display just the first include not the others.

Comment: My example is just as you described. Don't I include `extra.twig` multiple times?

Comment: What do you get in the profiler ? I have: https://imgur.com/GOQQpPl using Twig 2.5.0

Comment: You aren't using `blocks` inside the included template right? Because that won't work

Comment: @JulesR I upated my question with screen from my profiler. It detects the rendring count. I do use blocks.

Comment: Can you also include the template code ?

Comment: @JulesR I updated my question.

Comment: Hm where are your includes ?

Comment: In the part1.html.twig and part2.html.twig those two tempaltes are included in index.html.twig `{% include 'files-upload/files_preview.html.twig' with {source:'source'}  %}`

Comment: So as I said: Includes can't alter `blocks` of their callers. See [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1360) for more information about this